# Empty $request->request and $request->files with multipart/form-data

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, php-8, symfony6

I am trying to upload a form with a file to my server using AJAX, but Symfony doesn't parse the request body like it should. This is my PHP:

```
#[Route('/api/upload/file', name: "api_upload_file", methods: ['POST'])]
public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    dump($request->files->all());
    dump($request->request->all());
    dump($request->getContent());
...
```

and the dump output (The file part is cut out because it takes a lot of space) :

```
[]
```

```
[]
```

```
"""
------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subcategory"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="main_image"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="more_images"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="original_version"


------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version"


------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="original_title"


------WebKitFormBoundaryh4t0I09h9iTRNGme
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
"""
```

The request clearly gets through so I do not understand why the content is not parsed

Just in case, here is the javascript part : (This looks like JQuery but is not)

```
form.submit(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = createItemForm.formData();
        $.ajax('/api/upload/file', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log('uploaded');
            });
});
```

How should I do to get the files and the form values in $request->files and $request->request ?

Comment: Doesn't look like your submitted form actually has anything in it.  The request isn't going to put empty things into bags.

Comment: From that form All I can see is that you would expect $request->request->get('subcategory') would return 1, and title would return an empty string I guess?

Comment: @gview I cut out the file part of the request content for readabilty but forgot to mention it :/

Comment: even if we don't take the file into account I should get the results that you mention but I don't; they are all equal to null

Comment: Look at the submission in the devtools console network tab.  Maybe you'll see something wrong in there.

Comment: @Petersuib I don't think file-upload works this way. As long as I know, uploading file via AJAX isn't that trivial as it might look like. Try to "submit" a simple form (text type + select) and look if it gets though

Comment: Submitting a simple form did not work. I guess I'll just submit it like a proper form since it works when I do it that way... Thanks for you help

Comment: DO NOT specify the `Content-Type` header yourself, when trying to make such a multipart request. That header needs to include the boundary value (so that the receiver will know how to parse this request) - if you specify it yourself, as just `multipart/form-data`, then that will be missing. These request libraries usually know how to properly set it on their own, based on that you are passing in a FormData instance.

Comment: It worked @CBroe ! can't believe I just had to not specify the content-type lol. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DO NOT specify the `Content-Type` header yourself, when trying to make such a multipart request. That header needs to include the boundary value (so that the receiver will know how to parse this request) - if you specify it yourself, as just `multipart/form-data`, then that will be missing.

These request libraries usually know how to properly set it on their own, based on that you are passing in a FormData instance.